# It's taking almost 5 seconds for the data in my ng-repeat to redraw after I change the source

Tags: angularjs

I have a table on my page that is populated like this:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="row in grid.view = (grid.data | filter:isProblemInRange )">
```

I have the following function:

```
$scope.gridReset = function () {
   $scope.grid.data = angular.copy($scope.grid.backup);
   $scope.gridForm.$setPristine();
};
```

The function replaces the data in $scope.grid.data with a backup.

When it runs the angular.copy seems to take no time to run but the data on the screen
takes about 5 seconds before I see it changing to the backup copy. Is there anything
I could do to speed this up?

Here's the function isProblemInRange:

```
$scope.isProblemInRange = function (row) {
   return (row.problemId >= $scope.pidLower || $scope.pidLower == null || $scope.pidLower == "") &&
           (row.problemId < $scope.pidUpper || $scope.pidUpper == null || $scope.pidUpper == "")
};
```

I have approximately 500 rows in the grid.data

Comment: Try filtering your data in your controller not the ng-repeat directive.

Comment: Could you post your filter- `isProblemInRange`.  And how big is grid.data?

Comment: If you've got 500 rows and more then 4 columns you should consider using paging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. Does your data has to be bound only once for each change?

- `ng-repeat` sets a `$watch` for each item and within each `$digest` it dirty checks **all** registered `$$watchers`. If you have 2000+ of these `$$watchers` then your application will not be responsive (maybe until `object.observe`) and there is no way to fix it without reducing the amount of registered `$$watchers`.
- You must read @Misko Hevery's answer: [How does data binding work in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/databinding-in-angularjs)
- Check **bindonce** if it suites your requirements: https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce

#### 2. If you have indexes then you can help `ng-repeat`.

- `ng-repeat` without `track by` **removes all DOM elements** every time your array/object is overridden just to **recreate all DOM** elements again. If you have 1000+ elements that is slowwwwww.
- angular.js 1.2 introduced `track by` syntax for `ng-repeat` to solve this issue.
- Check this article : [Using Track By With ng-Repeat In Angular.js 1.2](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2556-Using-Track-By-With-ngRepeat-In-AngularJS-1-2.htm)

#### 3. If you **must** have a huge amount of dynamic bindings?

- You probably don't , use pagination whenever possible.
- If not , then you must write advanced stuff (like **custom repeaters** and **dynamic DOM insertions**)
- Check this article: [angularjs-my-solution-to-the-ng-repeat-performance-problem](http://www.williambrownstreet.net/blog/2013/07/angularjs-my-solution-to-the-ng-repeat-performance-problem/)
- and this also: [angularjs-1200ms-to-35ms](http://blog.scalyr.com/2013/10/31/angularjs-1200ms-to-35ms/)

#### what ng-repeat watches?

`ng-repeat` uses `$scope.$watchCollection`, from the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope):

> #### $watchCollection(obj, listener)
>
> Shallow watches the properties of an object and fires whenever any of the properties change (for arrays, **this implies watching the array items**; for object maps, this implies watching the properties). If a change is detected, the listener callback is fired.

That means if you have an array with 1000 objects (`[1..1000]`) then you end up with 1000 dirty checks with each $digest, one for each item(property).

#### `ng-repeat` and the DOM

- If you override the collection object itself (`grid.data` in the question above), all elements are removed from the DOM (unless you use `track by`) because by default, `ng-reapet` uses $$hashkeys for tracking changes. Those $$hashkeys are lost whenever the collection is replaced.
- If items are removed or added to the array without overriding it, then only these items are removed / added to the DOM.

Comment: `ng-repeat` watches the collection, not each item. Furthermore it does not remove all DOM elements when the data changes. It removes an element when an object has been removed.

Comment: @zeroflagL, I updated my answer, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It's alright. To be precise: The dirty check done by `$watchCollection` is done by comparing the entries with `!==`. So it's fast, even with large arrays.

Comment: @zeroflagL I tried my best. I'll be glad if you can edit my answer to be more clear and precise.